# WPF: Tree Expansion key combination

Tags: wpf, windows

Hi all I have created the WPF Tree which has three level of nodes.

Each will expand on mouse click or use of **"+"** key: With use of "TreeViewItem.Expanded".

Now I want to code Expansion of tree at load time.
This is to save the Click of User to get the information.

**I want to know below things from SO:**

1. Is there is any combination of key which will
   Expand all the tree nodes(As **"+"** will expand the one level of tree).
2. Or Is there is any property to generate the
   Event for the expansion of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, nothing built in.
2. No, again nothing built in.

That being said, it's a fairly trivial matter to intercept a key press event and enumerate your nodes and set the `TreeViewItem.Expanded = true;`.

Answer (score 0):

[TreeViewItem.ExpandSubTree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.expandsubtree.aspx) will expand the item and all of its children. If the TreeViewItem happens to be the root item, the entire tree will be expanded.